# How is the actual baryonic density calculated from critical mass?

Tags: cosmology

The Planck 2018 results give the Baryonic Density as: $\Omega_B h^2=0.0224$.  I want to calculate the actual density based on the parameters.  The same report tells us that $H_0=67.4$.  We know that the critical density is:
$$\rho_c=\frac{3 H^2}{8 \pi G}$$
$$\rho_c=8.53\times 10^{-27}\space kg\space m^{-3}$$
So if I want to get an actual value for the current baryon density, do I perform this operation:
$$\Omega_B h^2\space \rho_c = 0.0224 * (\frac{67.4}{100})^2 * 8.53\times 10^{-27}\space kg\space m^{-3}=8.68\times 10^{-29}\space kg\space m^{-3}$$
or is the right way to interpret the density as (note that we don't use the $h^2$ factor):
$$\Omega_B\space \rho_c = 0.0224 * 8.53\times 10^{-27}\space kg\space m^{-3}=1.91\times 10^{-28}\space kg\space m^{-3}$$
Or, is the notation really, really, really backwards and it should be:
$$\Omega_B h^{-2}\space \rho_c = 0.0224 * (\frac{67.4}{100})^{-2} * 8.53\times 10^{-27}\space kg\space m^{-3}=4.21\times 10^{-28}\space kg\space m^{-3}$$

The last one seems to make the most sense, because it gives a baryonic percent of critical density of 5%, which is what you hear quoted often.

Which is the right Hubble-adjusted value for baryonic density and, if the last formula is right, why is the value quoted as $\Omega_B h^2$ instead of $\Omega_B h^{-2}$ in the Planck study?

Comment: Neither of your evaluations makes sense because you haven’t substituted the values that the symbols have.

Comment: If the $\Omega$ isn't a fraction of critical density, then please provide the right method of calculating the actual density from these parameters.

Comment: I’m not talking about the interpretation, I’m talking about the evaluation.

Comment: I started with the Planck 2013 results, then decided to update it to the 2018 results.  If I got something wrong, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: The third evaluation that you’ve added makes the same mistake as the first two: the value of $\Omega_B$ is *not* 0.0224. There is nothing “backward” about any of the notation.

Comment: @G.Smith - I'm not a student.  I've got a gazillion things in my head right now.  At another time I might have appreciated the zen lesson.  $$\Omega_B h^2=0.0224$$  $$\Omega_B=\frac{0.0224}{h^2}$$  $$\Omega_B=0.0224 h^{-2}$$ $$\rho_B=\Omega_B\space \rho_c=0.022\space 0.684^{-2}\space 8.53\times 10^{-27}=4.21\times 10^{-28}\space kg\space m^{-3}$$

Comment: That’s correct. I read your profile and am aware that you are not a student.

Comment: Would it in anyway be helpful if the question was just answered ?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that dislexia got in the way of interpreting the $\Omega_B h^2=0.0224$ notation properly.  As the conversation above goes, the answer - based on the Planck 2018 results - is:
$$\Omega_Bh^2=0.0224$$
$$\Omega_B=\frac{0.0224}{h^2}$$
$$\Omega_B=0.0224h^{-2}$$
$$\rho_B=\Omega_B\cdot \rho_c=0.0224\cdot 0.674^{-2}\cdot 8.53\times 10^{-27}\space kg\space m^{-3}=4.21\times 10^{-28}\space kg\space m^{-3}$$
I'd appreciate it if someone could just double check that this is the right value.

Comment: The final number looks fine to me, I think that should be $0.674^{-2}$ though.

Comment: @J.Murray- Yes.  Thanks for the correction.